# How to convert the JSON response to Map in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a JSON response from my API call. The format is like this.

```
[
  {
    "hotelname": "A",
    "roomno": "101",
    "occupancy": "4"
  },
  {
    "hotelname": "A",
    "roomno": "102",
    "occupancy": "3"
  },
  {
    "hotelname": "B",
    "roomno": "101",
    "occupancy": "4"
  },
  {
    "hotelname": "B",
    "roomno": "202",
    "occupancy": "3"
  }
]
```

I want to write a code where in one dropdown list displays the names of the hotels(A,B,C etc) the other dropdown should display the corresponding roomno.

To achieve this i would like to convert my JSON response to a MAP like the below.

```
 Map<String,String> _hoteldata = {
    "101":"A",
    "102":"A",
    "101":"B",
    "202":"B",

  };
```

Comment: A map like this cannot exist, because the keys are not unique.

Comment: @bereal My keys are unique now. I have updated my question. Is it possible  now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you parse the json using [`jsonDecode()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html), then create a map from the list, for example, using [`Map.fromEntries()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/Map.fromEntries.html):

```
import 'dart:convert';
var rooms = jsonDecode(json) as List;
var hotelData = Map.fromEntries(
  rooms.map((room) => MapEntry(room['roomno'], room['hotelname']))
);
```